# Matrix associated with representation $\rho_{g}(e_{k})=e_{gk}$ in a finite group $G$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$, $V=\left \langle e_{g}\colon g\in G \right \rangle_{\mathbb{K}}$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space where the basis is indexed by $G$. Given the representation $\rho\colon G \to GL(V)$ defined by $\rho_{g}(e_{k})=e_{gk}$, I want to understand the matrix representing each of these automorphisms and their respective traces. I started by ordering the basis $\mathcal{B}=(e_{g_{1}},\dots,e_{g_{n}})$. Now, for the matrix $[\rho_{g}]_{\mathcal{B}}$ I think that there will be a one on the diagonal $[\rho_{g}]_{kk}$ as long as $\rho_{g}(e_{g_{k}}) = e_{gg_{k}} = e_{g_{k}}$, that happens only if $gg_{k}=g_{k}$, i.e. $g=e$, then the trace is zero if $g$ is not the identity and $n$ if $g$ is the identity.

I don't know if the reasoning is right because I understand that if $G$ were the symmetric group or some subgroup of it, the trace would be given by the indices that the permutation leaves fixed. But in this case which is given by a left multiplication I think the only way to get a one in the diagonal is for $g$ to be the identity. I would appreciate your help in clarifying if it is ok.

Comment: You consider here two different representations of the symmetric group. For the first one (by left multiplication), you make $S_n$ act on a vector space that has dimension $n!$ ; for the second one (given by $\sigma.e_i = e_{\sigma(i)}$, $S_n$ acts on a vector space that has dimension $n$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, I understand that. So with respect to the matrices of the action by left multiplication, they would of the style that I mentioned? or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are correct. The trace is $n$ if $g=e$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct. You are actually considering the left regular representation of $G$, which decomposes as $\oplus_{V\in \Omega} \dim(V)V$ (when e.g. $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$) where $\Omega$ is the set of all non-isomorphic irreducible representations of $G$.